# Do jquery like operations on an object decorated with viewchild

Tags: jquery, angular

Is it possible to query the DOM of an object decorated by Viewchild like I would do with jQuery ?

I have to do stuff like below to the child's DOM.

```
  @ViewChild('someComponent') child: SomeComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.child.queryTheDomElementFor('some tag');
     this.child.getDomElementThatContains('specific Content');
     this.child.setCss(this.child.someNode, 'css rules');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

```
@ViewChild('someComponent') someComponent: SomeComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     document.querySelectorAll(..);
     document.getElementById(..);
     document.getElementByClass(..);
 // also nativeElement property can be used as
     this.someComponent.nativeElement.children
  }

<element #someComponent> </element>
```

Update :

You can use component methods as you have declared it as viewChild as

```
this.someComponent.someMethod()
```

Comment: SomeComponent class doesn't have those jQuery methods.

Comment: which jQuery method? which components

Comment: SomeComponent Class doesn't have methods querySelectorAll etc.

Comment: There is now way I can use those methods on this.someComponent ?